# Transparent object isn't showing the intersecting object inside it

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

The cylinder has raytrace transparency on and it does show the texture of the globe through it but not the squares. How come the grid doesn't show through the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: What render engine are you using? How did you make the wireframe material? How are you rendering this? Please add more info to your question about your material setup, and if possible a blend file

Comment: I'm using Blender Render. The wireframe is made by creating cubes and changing the material to wire. I'm rendering it with the default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that rendering wireframes inside other materials or through effects like refraction is not supported since the wireframe is itself sort of a "2D-like effect.

Try using a *Wireframe* modifier in your cubes instead, that should be visible inside refractive materials, at the expense of extra geometry.